# Have AND Clause if variable is not null in MySQL Select

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to make an If statement inside SQL Select query, I would like to apply only if variable $department is different than NULL. if the variable is different then Null place `P2.department = P1.department` as AND Clause.

The query line is as follows:

```
,(SELECT SUM(P2.fee) FROM cases P2 WHERE 
 IF('$department' IS NULL, 0, P2.department = P1.department) AND curency = 1) as fee_USD
```

In the current situation the query is working but it displays wrong results. My question is this is the best way to include `P2.department = P1.department AND` inside the query. Any help is welcome.

Here is the full query:

```
                       SELECT 
                       P1.id
                      ,P1.department
                      ,P1.curency
                      ,P1.fee   
                      ,count(P1.id) as count_cases
                      ,(SELECT SUM(P2.fee) FROM cases P2 WHERE 
                      IF('$department' IS NULL, 0, P2.department = P1.department) 
                      AND curency = 1) as fee_USD                                           

                    FROM cases P1 WHERE 1";                                                 
                            if (!empty($department)) { $sql .= " AND P1.department = '$department'"; }
                            if (!empty($status)) { $sql .= " AND P1.status = '$status'"; }
```

Comment: you can use the query concatenation as a string after doing the test on null and later execute it !! try to clarify more your query please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no need to use `IF`, just `AND` will be also well;)

```
,(SELECT SUM(P2.fee) FROM cases P2 WHERE 
 curency = 1 AND '$department' IS NOT NULL AND P2.department = P1.department) as fee_USD
```

***Edited***

```
,(SELECT SUM(P2.fee) FROM cases P2 WHERE 
 curency = 1 AND ('$department' = '0' OR P2.department = P1.department)) as fee_USD
```

This query will do `P2.department = P1.department` only when `$department` is not 0.

Comment: Here the condition P2.department = P1.department will be executed no matter the state of $department . I wish this condition to be erased in case if $department is 0

Comment: @JohnSiniger What if $department is null? If just for `0`, check the ***Edited*** answer please.

Comment: if is 0 then nothing have to happen, P2.department = P1.department have not to be inside the WHERE as a condition.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as you are trying to interpolate a PHP variable into a qouted SQL string literal. (btw.: Interpolation in SQL is almost always a bad idea, except you really know the dynamic content at development time; look for "SQL injection".) A string literal will never be `NULL`. If PHP `NULL` is interpolated into a string, it will result in an empty string. The SQL `$sql = "WHERE ('$department' = '' OR ...)` would work to ignore the following condition and `$sql = "WHERE '$department' != '' AND ...` would require the variable to be set or the row will not be selected at all, however, you should choose a safer way. Since the PHP variable will not change during the execution of SQL, just build your SQL string dependent on the the PHP variable is NULL or not:

```
$department_cond = is_null($department) ? '' : ' `P2`.`department` = `P1`.`department` AND';

$sql = "... ,(SELECT SUM(`P2`.`fee`) FROM `cases` `P2` WHERE{$department_cond} curency = 1) `fee_USD`;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CASE`:

```
,(SELECT SUM(P2.fee) FROM cases P2 WHERE 
 curency = 1 AND (CASE WHEN '$department' != 'null' THEN P2.department = P1.department END)) as fee_USD
```